# VBA values from dynamically added combobox

Tags: vba, excel

First post here. Self-taught VBA so I'm always aware that code may not be perfect. Anyway...

Creating a Userform Questionnaire. I don't know how many questions there will be, and I want it to be easy for anyone to add new questions to the form. Idea is to have the questions listed on a Sheet so that as new questions are added, the userbox will resize accordingly and add in all the questions.

Doing this was no problem:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Activate()
    QuestionsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("QuestionData").Range("A:A")) - 1
    ResultsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("QuestionData").Range("B:B")) - 1
    DepartmentCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("QuestionData").Range("C:C")) - 1
    QuestionForm1.ScrollHeight = (QuestionsCount) * 70
    QuestionForm1.Width = 258
    CommandButton1.Top = (QuestionsCount - 1) * 70
    CommandButton1.Left = 42
    CommandButton2.Top = (QuestionsCount - 1) * 70
    CommandButton2.Left = 132

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim QQ(1 To 100) As MSForms.Control
    Dim QA(1 To 100) As MSForms.Control
    For i = 5 To QuestionsCount
        Set QQ(i) = QuestionForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1")
        Set QA(i) = QuestionForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.ComboBox.1")
        With QQ(i)
            .Caption = Sheets("QuestionData").Range("A" & (i + 1))
            .Width = 84
            .Top = i * 58
            .Left = 24
            .Name = "Label" & i
        End With
        With QA(i)
            .RowSource = "QuestionData!B2:B" & ResultsCount + 1
            .Width = 96
            .Top = i * 58
            .Left = 138
            .Name = "Combo" & i
            .Value = ""
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Userform is created and all the questions I want are there (positioning of the command buttons isn't great, I know, will fix this soon)

The only problem is taking the values. The answers are in a ComboBox, the user will select the answers they want and click the Submit button. The idea was to then take the values from each `comboBox` and put them into another sheet.
The issue I'm having is that the global variables seem to disappear at the end of the sub. So when the user inserts their answers and clicks Submit, the macro tries to take values that aren't there.

What are the names of the added ComboBoxes? Where are their values stored? Is there a way to not End Sub so that the values stay as Global Variables? Any other ideas on what to do?

Any help would be appreciated...hopefully I've explained myself well!

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but if it is to get the values of `ComboBoxes` after you've hidden your form? then, you can still access the `ComboBoxes` even though the form is not visible. You can declare a public variable in a module (i.e. `Public oMyForm as New <your form name here>`). You can then access any of forms objects or form properties in your UDF's by simply accessing this object (i.e. `oMyForm.myCombobox.Value`.. where `myCombobox` would be the actual name of your combobox)

Answer (score 0):

You've named your comboboxes using `.Name = "Combo" & i`.

So you could create a routine that runs on pressing a SUBMIT button or similar that reads the values with:

```
QuestionForm1.Controls("Combo5").Value
```

You could also set this up as a loop to build an array with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ResultsCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("QuestionData").Range("B:B")) - 1
    Dim chosenvalue(100)

    For i = 5 To ResultsCount
        chosenvalue(i) = QuestionForm1.Controls("Combo" & i).Value
        Debug.Print "Button " & i & " set to " & chosenvalue(i)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That's what I originally thought. But looking in the Locals window, it is as if it doesn't exist. None of the new ComboBoxes I have added appear.
If I break before the end of the Sub, I can see them, but not once the Sub has ended and the form is still on screen.

Comment: Are you `Unload`ing or closing the form somewhere, before you attempt to read the values?

Comment: No. So the form is loading, the controls are being added and then the sub is ending. At this point, the form stays on screen while the user can change the answers that they pick - this all works fine.
I then have a submit button which I want to take the answers and paste them into a sheet on the attached file. But the answers cant be found as when the sub ends, they disappear.

Comment: I've just mocked this up here and noticed that for some reason your loop starts at 5.. so I've altered my example to suit. PS. This works fine on my mockup.

Comment: That is what I had originally. If i try it, i get Run-time error: '-2147024809 (80070057) Could not find the specified object. The debugger then highlights 
    QuestionForm1.Controls("Combo" & i).Value
Right enough, then I check my Locals list, it is no where to be seen.

PS. starts at i =5 because I have 4 comboboxes that I have put in myself

Comment: Sorry @MattyGee, I can't recreate this myself. I'm getting no problems with the `CommandButton1_Click()` code above.